# I'm confused as to when I should be using functions and methods in python

Tags: function, methods

I'm getting advice from everyone to use functions and methods to organize my codes and I agree, it will make for a more organized code. But I just saw some guy on YouTube make a super complicated program without ever defining a function or creating a class, and it was really organized and functioned perfectly fine. So my question is when should I use functions and methods in my code, and when is it better not to.

I'm not trying to deny the usefulness of functions and methods, it's just that I'm always confused whether I should or shouldn't use them in various situations.

Answer (score 0):

Without functions a code will be too long. It is better to include functions so that you don't have to write the same lines repeatedly. 
It actually depends on your code. If certain lines will be repeated, it is better to declare functions. If not, you don't need to.